# AVCaptureDevice flashMode not working

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

In an app using `AVCaptureSession` and `AVCaptureDevice`, I am taking pictures and it goes as expected.

I decided to implement the use of the flash and there troubles are coming.

Here is the code I added, after searching on the net on how to use the flash in an iOS app:

```
    if captureDevice.hasFlash && captureDevice.isFlashModeSupported(.On) {
        do {try captureDevice.lockForConfiguration()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("captureDevice.lockForConfiguration FAILED")
            print(error.code)
        }
        captureDevice.flashMode = .On
        captureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
        captureSession.commitConfiguration()
    }
```

It compiles OK but when I try to take a photo, the app crashes with the following error:

```
Error on taking a picture:
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation couldn’t be completed." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x14e176f40 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16800 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Undefined error（-16800）, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed.}
```

Since I have never used the flash before, it may well be a newbie error. But I haven’t, at this point, been able to figure out what was wrong.
If anyone has experience using the flash in an app, please let me know what may be the issue.

Comment: I guess this error is nothing to do with flashlight. Are you saving the taken photo using `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection`?

Comment: Yes I am using captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection. I believe you that this error has nothing to do with flashlight. But what I know is that if I do not use the code I mentioned in my question then the problem disappears.

Comment: Your capture device don't have the expected device. It is NULL. Keep a breakpoint and check it.

Comment: No that was not the problem. Thanks for the indication anyway.
Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097389/cant-use-avcapturedevice-with-a-flash for my own answer to this issue.
The link to the flash light was only indirect (as you suggested in your first comment).

Comment: Can you please share your project code? it is easy to debug

Comment: Yes I could, but it is now working. I explained my solution in the link above.